# Matlab evaluating a string containing operations

Tags: string, matlab, struct, mapping, eval

I have a first structure like:

```
struct1.Vx.Value=10;  
struct1.Vy.Value=2;
```

In a 2nd structure, I write operations as strings:

```
struct2.param1.map='sqrt(Vx^2+Vy^2)';  
struct2.param2.map='Vx+Vy';
```

What is the most efficient way to set:

```
struct2.param1.value= [sqrt(10^2+2^2)=10.198]  
struct2.param2.value= [10+2=12]
```

I found a solution using `assignin` and `fieldnames` on struct1 to create variables Vx=10 and Vy=2
then, I use `eval()` on struct2 to perform the operations.
Ok, it works but I don't like this solution reading what is said on eval()...

Is there a more efficient way to do what I want?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think you'll get any solution that is "nice" in `eval`...

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
Perhaps I should look at `matlabFunction`? [link to help](http://www.mathworks.fr/fr/help/symbolic/matlabfunction.html)

Answer (score 0):

I manage to find a good solution, formating my data differently:

```
 s.Vx = 10;
 s.Vy = 2;

 Map1 = 'sqrt( s.Vx^2+ s.Vy^2)';
 FunctionMap1 = str2func( [@(s) Map1] );
```

And then I can evaluate my function handle simply with:

```
 Value = FunctionMap1(s)
```